# What is the recommended way to re-use methods inside ES6 React Components?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns

The React team [advises against using mixins](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html). Their [suggestion for utility methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html#utility-methods) is to put them into a module and import them. I would be happy to do this, but their example doesn't show how to do that when you need `this`.

Thus, I find myself constantly copying this method,

```
updateState = updates => {
    this.setState(state => update(state, updates));
};
```

And a few others into all my components. Is there a better, non-deprecated way to re-use "methods"?

By "method" I mean a non-static function utilizing `this`.

Answer (score 1):

**ES7 class properties** [learn more](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)

```
    // updateState.js
    function updateState() {
        this.setState(state => update(state, updates));
    };

    // App.js
    import updateState from './updateState.js'

    class App extends Compnent {
        updateState = updateState.bind(this);
    }
```